# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter Spring Security 2.0.8

Tags: spring, spring-security, forms-authentication

i'm trying to downgrade a custom legacy authentication provider developed with Spring-Security 3.x to the 2.0.8 one.

My authentication mechanism uses an "user and password form login..."

The legacy project uses as Spring Security Filter a custom extension of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class

```
public class AuthenticationProcessingFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     ...
    }
}
```

But Spring Security 2.0.8 doesn't provide that class.

So is there a valid alternative to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, or have i to use the classic SpringSecurityFilter?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find by myself
org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter;